# Chern connections theorem problem

Tags: complex-geometry

I'm reading the book of Andrei Moroianu, "Lectures on kahler geometry" and at the page 79 is this theorem:

[image]

I don't understand the last proposition. namely the fact that $\nabla_Z(H(\sigma))=H(\nabla_{\over{Z}}\sigma)$

Comment: The LHS being $\mathbb{C}$-linear in $Z$ so inside the $H$ of the RHS must be antilinear in $Z$, i.e., only have $\bar{Z}$ and no $Z$.  Moreover we know it is $\nabla_X\sigma$ for real $X$ so it must be $\nabla_{\bar{Z}}\sigma$.